# Sharepoint Custom Sequential workflow using Visual studio 2008 not sending email

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, email, workflow

I have created a Sharepoint custom Sequential workflow. I have to use the SendEmail activity to send an alert at various steps. I tried the following code:

```
        this.sendalertEmail.To = "somebody@somwhere.com";

        this.sendalertEmail.From = "somebody@somwhere.com";

        this.sendalertEmail.Subject = "Regarding email";

        this.sendalertEmail.Body = @"This is an automated email <b>response</b>";
```

i have configured teh outgoing settings in my server with Smtp server and other details.

it says "The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly." please help

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure SMTP is setup correctly and that your smtp server is allowing relay?

Send some test emails using a tool like the [SMTP Test Tool](http://www.simplecomtools.com/productcart/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=5&idcategory=5) or [Telnet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153119) on your SharePoint servers to send some test emails.